# Can someone help me understand this? int *& pr

Tags: c++, variables, pointers

I found this in a final exam:

```
int a = 564;
int* pa = &a;
int *& pr = pa;
cout << *pr;
```

According to the multiple choice answer, the code is valid, and displays the value of a.

But I'm confused about evaluation and precedence for line 3. Order of operations for C states that * and & have the same order. So, would it then be `int *(&pr)`? How can this be described in words?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a reference to a pointer. In C, you would express that as a pointer to a pointer.

You could write something like this:

```
// C++ style
void update_my_ptr(int*& ptr) { ptr = new int[1024]; }

// C style
void update_my_ptr_c(int **ptr) { *ptr = malloc(1024 * sizeof(int)); }

int main()
{
   int *ptr;
   update_my_ptr(ptr);
   // Here ptr is allocated!

}
```

Comment: Interesting. I've used pointer-to-pointer in C, so this analogy is very useful to understanding the syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The third line defines a pointer reference (or a reference to a pointer, if you want). Assigning it to a pointer makes `pr` to actually be an alias to `pa`, and when evaluated, it points where `pa` points to, that is, `a`.

In the declaration of a variable, `*` and `&` don't have the meaning of *operators*, so precedence doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Line three creates a reference (read: alias) of a pointer to an `int`. If you were to set `pr` to 0, `pa` would also be equal to 0 (and vice-versa).